# For some reason my Backbone Cocktail.js mixin Event is being overwritten

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, mixins, cocktail.js

**My mixin**

```
window.MyMixins = {}

MyMixins.GlobalViewMethods =

  events:
    'click #skipit' : 'skipit'
```

**my view**

```
Maestra.Views.Questions ||= {}

class Maestra.Views.Questions.Prereq extends Backbone.View
  @mixin MyMixins.GlobalViewMethods

  template: JST["backbone/templates/questions/prereq"]

  events:
    "click #stepone"                        : "open_stepone"
    "click #steptwo"                        : "open_steptwo"
    "click #stepthree"                      : "open_stepthree"
    "click #stepone, #steptwo, #stepthree"  : "add_complete"    
    "click #iamstupidready"                 : "check_question"
```

When I run this, my mixin event does not work. However, if I remove all my events from my View, then the mixin event works. Otherwise, all the other events work, and the View's events always override the Mixin's events. Everything else klobbers fine ( render functions, constructor methods, etc. )

Is my syntax incorrect? Why is this not letting me mixin events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when `@mixin` runs:

```
@mixin MyMixins.GlobalViewMethods
```

There is no `events` in the class so no merging is done. Then, you hit the `events`:

```
events:
  "click #stepone"                        : "open_stepone"
  #...
```

and CoffeeScript will overwrite the `events` that `@mixin` added (remember that `@mixin` knows about merging, CoffeeScript doesn't). If we look at a simplified example, you should see what's going on; this CoffeeScript:

```
class V extends Backbone.View
  @mixin MyMixins.GlobalViewMethods
  events:
    "click #in_v" : "in_v"
```

becomes this JavaScript (with a bunch of noisy boilerplate removed):

```
V = (function(_super) {
  //...
  function V() {
    _ref = V.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    return _ref;
  }

  V.mixin(MyMixins.GlobalViewMethods);

  V.prototype.events = {
    "click #in_v": "in_v"
  };

  return V;

})(Backbone.View);
```

Now you can see that `@mixin` (`V.mixin`) runs and merges some `events` into the non-existent `V.prototype.events` and then `V.prototype.events` is overwritten with the `events` from `V`.

How do you solve an ordering problem? Well, you just adjust the order by putting your `@mixin` call at the bottom:

```
class V extends Backbone.View
  events:
    "click #in_v" : "in_v"
  @mixin MyMixins.GlobalViewMethods
```

Now `@mixin` will see the `events` in `V` and do some merging.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2f9hV/1/

Comment: Mu! Thanks so much for this friend! I really appreciate it. I couldn't thank you enough.